# How to create a "whole packaged" library

Tags: java, android, libraries

I have an Android library project and I want to export the .jar with all the depdencies inside (external libs with armeabi, armeabi-v7a, etc). Is it possible or I must send my .jar with all these libs in another folder ?

EDIT : I work on Eclispe

My library uses external libs like GSON and some of them have .so files. These files are sorted into armeabi / X86 ... folders in /libs

On Eclipse I have right clicked on the /libs folder set it as source folder. Then my new project.jar was heavier, so all the depencies were inside. But when I imported it into another project and try to launch it, I have this error message :

> [2014-02-24 11:25:39 - com.testapp.demo] The library 'secretlib.jar'
>   contains native libraries that will not run on the device.
>   [2014-02-2411:25:39 - com.testapp.demo] The following libraries were
>   found: [2014-02-24 11:25:39 - com.testapp.demo]  -
>   armeabi/libx.so [2014-02-24 11:25:39 - com.testapp.demo]  -
>   armeabi/liby.so [2014-02-24 11:25:39 - com.testapp.demo]  -
>   armeabi/libmr.so

Comment: Technically it is possible, i think you want to know how it is possible with your IDE and/or build tools, so please specify them.

Comment: It is totally possible but it strongly depends on the way (and the tools) you are using to create your compiled version. Your IDE could provide some utilities for this and some building tools like Ant or Maven too. Can you give more insights about how you are creating the JAR package?

Comment: Oups, sorry, I have edited my question.

Comment: Use something like One-JAR etc, it should be doable with Android apps too.

Answer (score 0):

I had found that I could not get this to work, although I had seen several individuals have mentioned that it should be done otherwise.  The current SDK that I have available comes with the standard ReadME.txt file.  Within the file it requests the user to create the armabi folder and put the .so library file in there after importing their standard jar.  I had found that this wasn't a supported feature and that the developer would have to do an additional step.  But if you find otherwise, then I would love to hear otherwise and then I can remove that extra step from the developer in the next release.